# Background processes

Tags: ps, background-process, jobs

I have a script that needs to be run on background, if I run the same script on foreground, the script runs good and it wont stop until we manually interrupt (ctrl^c).

I am sure that the below command runs the script in background.

```
sudo -u webs ./spagent_L1 &
```

Once the above command is executed it will give the job number and the process number.

```
[1] 10118
```

And immediately after that if i press enter two times, the job gets stopped.

```
[1]+ Stopped    sudo -u webs ./spagent_L1
```

if I check the jobs running in background it shows that the job has been stopped.

```
$> jobs
[1]+ Stopped    sudo -u webs ./spagent_L1
```

Whereas if I check for process running, it shows like the above mentioned script is running.

```
$> ps -eo user,ppid,pid,cmd,state | grep -i spagent
root 10118 9383 0 05:42 pts/1 00:00:00 sudo -u webs ./spagent_L1 T
ape  10122 3983 0 05:42 pts/1 00:00:00 grep -i spagent R
```

Unless I kill the process 10118 the jobs command shows the output that the process is stopped. Once the process is killed, the jobs command doesn't return anything.

So, does the above output mean if the process is still running? Could anyone please help me understand what is happening up there. and how to run the script in background without getting it stopped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @val0x00ff I have mentioned it in my question itself, the output of `ps -ef | grep -i spagent`

Comment: If I use ps-eo, then I am getting the following error. Am I missing anything.
`$> ps -eo | grep web
ERROR: Format specification must follow -o.
********* simple selection *********  ********* selection by list *********
-A all processes                      -C by command name
-N negate selection                   -G by real group ID (supports names)
-a all w/ tty except session leaders  -U by real user ID (supports names)
-d all except session leaders         -g by session OR by effective group name
-e all processes                      -p by process ID`

Comment: looks like grep is expecting some kind of input (a file maybe ?)

Comment: @Archemar What do you mean by some kind of input? the output of `ps-ef` is passed to `grep -i spagent`

Comment: @sabarishjackson  could you PLEASE just copy/paste what I wrote in my first comment. Once again `ps -eo user,ppid,pid,cmd,state`

Comment: @val0x00ff I have edited the question. Please find the edited question with ps -eo user,ppid,pid,cmd,state

Comment: @sabarishjackson My bad, I did not see the `T` and `R` there. So if you `man ps | less '+/STATE'`  what does `T` tell you?

Comment: What happens when you run your script not in background? Does it get stopped too?
Stopped is the state of the process. Process can have multiple states (man ps and look for state). You should verify your process is running fine in the foreground before your run it at the background.

Comment: @Vinny Purpose of this script is, it invokes a GUI, which can be checked in the browser. If I run the script in foreground it is running perfectly until we hard interrupt it. But mentioned in the question is what happens if i run it in background using `&`. I dont think it is running in background, it stops immediately.  Even If i get the job number and start it using `bg 1` it  is going to `Stopped` state again. What could be the reason!

Comment: @val0x00ff `T Stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced.`

Comment: @sabarishjackson this means that the process got `SIGSTOP` and is put in `STOPPED` state until it gets a `SIGCONT` signal. Seems the process requires input. What happens if you run the program without `&` and then `ctrl+z` followed by `bg`. What happens then?

Comment: @sabarishjackson When running the script in background, check it's stdout and stderr by `tail -f /proc/<pid>/fd/1` and `tail -f /proc/<pid>/fd/2` to see it's output. There might be some error.

Comment: @sabarishjackson Also you can try this instead `nohup sudo -u webs ./spagent_L1 > some_log_file 2>&1 &` this will print the output to the file and then check it to see if you find the issue. `nohup` is a linux tool to run processes immune to hangups (even after the shell executed them is closed)

Comment: @val0x00ff Yeah, I was about to tell that. If i start the script in foreground and then `ctrl+z` followed by `bg`, it works.

Comment: @Vinny Yes I tried `sudo -u webs ./spagent_L1 > log_file_name &` As usual the script `Stopped` again and the size of the log file is `0 Bytes`

Comment: @Vinny THanks for that, The issue I face now is I couldn't run more than one script in background in a server. Suppose I have two scripts `spagent_L1` and `spagent_L2`, I need both the script to be running in background. If i try `nohup sudo -u webs ./spagent_L1 > some_log_file 2>&1 &` It runs perfectly in background, whereas if I try running `spagent_L2` in the same way, it is getting stopped immediately. But  If i start the second script in foreground and then `ctrl+z` followed by `bg`, it works. Could you please advise what could be the issue.

Comment: @sabarishjackson Check if the scripts are accessing the same files, or using the exact same resources or the same log files. These need to be unique per script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62904/discussion-between-sabarish-jackson-and-vinny).

Answer (score 0):

You can run the script in the background by doing: `(sudo -u webs ./spagent_L1 &)` you should then be able to close the terminal (if you are in DE) without closing that script.